# Recurrent sequence with two candidates for limit

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

We have a recurrent sequence defined as $x_0 \in [0;2], x_{n+1}={1 \over 4}x_n(5-x_n)$. We want to check it for convergence.

If $x_n \to g \implies x_{n+1} \to g$. Substituting this in the equation gives $g_1=0, g_2=1$. We can also notice that the same equation with $x_0$ will give us $x_0 \le x_1$ for $x_0 \in [0;1]$ and $x_0 \ge x_1$ for $x_0 \in [1;2]$, so we know whether to expect the sequence to increase or decrease (not a proof just yet). Now, we could show that for different values of $x_0$ the sequence is bounded from above (by 1) or below (by 0 or 1). My intuition is that $1$ is the more natural candidate for a limit. How can I prove this, though? Particularly for the case when the sequence decreases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

we have

$$4(x_{n+1}-1)=-x_n^2+5x_n-4$$

$$=(x_n-1)(4-x_n).$$

on the other hand

as $x_1\in[0,2]$, we have by induction

$$0\leq x_n \leq 2 \implies$$

$$0\leq(5- x_n)\leq 3 \implies$$

$$0\leq\frac{1}{4}x_n (5-x_n) \leq \frac{3}{2}<2 \implies$$

$$0\leq x_{n+1}\leq 2 \implies$$

$$-2\leq x_n-4\leq 2.$$

thus

$$|x_{n+1}-1|\leq \frac{1}{2}|x_n-1|$$

$$......< \frac{1}{2^n}|x_1-1|$$

therefore

$x_1=0$ or $x_1=1 \implies x_n=$constant.

in the other cases,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1.$$